# Python doesn't know to stop

Tags: python, pandas

Simple code is not working and am looking for some help.

df has 44000 rows of chat conversations in xml format. The root/child structure is below. I'm needing to grab all of the "< body >" entries from a row/chat and join into a single string; this output will go to the variable "test" within the dataframe. My code works but the loop does not stop. I know it works because it I stop the loop with the timeout code and inspect the dataframe, it is doing what it should. I just want the code to work without me having to use the timeout statement.

```
 <chat>
 <messages>
 <chat-message>
 <timestamp>2017-08-22T15:08:35.906-04:00</timestamp> 
  <name /> 
  <body>Hello Mikey, I see you want to chat with us today about: Account    
  Assistance. If you are chatting on a mobile device or tablet, your        
  session will end if you navigate away from the chat window. A 
  representative will be with you momentarily.
  </body> 
  <usertype>system</usertype> 
  </chat-message>
  <chat-message>

def msgg(row):
    root = ET.fromstring(row)
    toad = ['the'] #Saving something in toad since python will not let you append to an empty list   
    for body in root.findall('messages/chat-message/body'):
         toad.append(body.text)    
    return toad

timeout = time.time() + 60*10    

for row in df5['chat']:
      df5['test'] = df5['chat'].apply(msgg)
      if time.time() > timeout: break
```

The code does what I want but does not exit the for loop. If I had not added the

```
if time.time() > timeout: break
```

block of code, the program would keep running. I can let it run for 1 minute with the break code and the resulting dataset is complete. Without the break, it'll run for 1 hour (probably longer but I hit the red stop box after an hour. Any thoughts as to why python will not stop eventhough it's done? Thanks in advance.

> P.S.: For anyone tempted to scream this is a duplicate post and advocate for it's removal, please note it's a different question. My other post was asking about handling the parsing error. This is asking about handling a bad loop.

Tried this

```
for index,row in df5.iterrows():
    row['test'] = row['chat'].apply(msgg)
```

and got a

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Tried this

```
for index,row in df5.itertuples():
    row['test'][index] = row['chat'][index].apply(msgg)
```

and got

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: are you sure your loop does what it's supposed to do? you're not even using the `row` variable...

Comment: please fix your indentation. it's impossible to tell where one block ends and the next begins...

Comment: #Saving something in toad since python will not let you append to an empty list ???

Comment: @ Felix, I wonder could that be the problem. row stays at some value and the for loop goes forever. I tried adding a line row + after the apply line and it did not work

Comment: Could it be that the long running loop is in msgg?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as et2

```
def msgg(row):
    parser = et2.XMLParser(recover=True)
    root = ET.fromstring(row, parser=parser)
    toad = ['the '] 
    for body in root.findall('messages/chat-message/body'):
      toad.append(body.text)
return "".join(toad)

for row in range(df5.shape[0]):
  if re.findall(r"xml version=",df5['chat'][row]):            
    df5['test'][row] = msgg(df5['chat'][row])
```

Considering the simplicity of the answer, I guess I did a poor job posing the question considering the lack of responses. Thanks to all who tried to help.